# The Zen of Software Rec

Tags: discussion, question-quality, answer-quality

So a bit of fun,
but also possibly useful.

Many of you would be aware of the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> ```
> Beautiful is better than ugly.
> Explicit is better than implicit.
> Simple is better than complex.
> Complex is better than complicated.
> Flat is better than nested.
> Sparse is better than dense.
> Readability counts.
> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
> Although practicality beats purity.
> Errors should never pass silently.
> Unless explicitly silenced.
> In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
> Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
> Now is better than never.
> Although never is often better than *right* now.
> If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
> If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
> Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
> ```

Lets think up a Zen of Software Rec.
For both answers and questions.

We can draw upon some great meta posts.

Getting down ideas like:
 - What a answer should look like (Syle wise)
 - One answer per post, execpt when you shouldn't
 - Special cases are what we are here for 
 - First person expeirence is a must

So lets capture our guidelines into a beautiful zen like form.

I'll make my own entry into this 
but here is one to get started:

**-Dot Points are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those**

I don't think out Zen needs to be as long.

Answer (score 2):

- Person Experience is the value we add over Google.
- Explicit Requirements are better than implicit.
- Specific is better than Broad.
- Broad is better than Speculative.
- Pricing should be listed
- as should OS/Platform
- Readability counts.
- Special cases problems are what we are here for.
- Although practicality beats perfect match of requirements.
- Poor questions should never pass silently.
- But be nice and help them get fixed
- In the face of ambiguity, Comment, then Edit if you can resolve it.
- Question as if you expect there to be one, and Only one answer to
  your question.
- But, Answer with the knowledge of the wider context of the many solutions.
- Answering now is better than no answer being given
- But not answering at all is better than rushing your answer
- If the operation of the software for this task is hard to explain, it's a bad
  solution.
- If the operation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
- Dotpoints are one honking great idea -let's do more of those!

**I don't feel I've captured everything I should in this.
I think I got carried away imitating the Zen of Python.
Feel Free to copy and paste and edit  for your own answers**